# Oracle, object table & nested tables

Tags: oracle, nested-table

Say I have 2 objects MY_OBJ, MY_NESTED_TABLE_OBJ

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_NESTED_TABLE_OBJ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_OBJ AS OBJECT (
    simple_atribute NUMBER(6),
    table_attribute MY_NESTED_TABLE_OBJ,
    MEMBER PROCEDURE doStuff(text VARCHAR2)
) NOT FINAL INSTANTIABLE;
```

MY_OBJ's table

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_MY_OBJ OF MY_OBJ
(  CONSTRAINT PK_simple_atribute PRIMARY KEY(simple_atribute))
NESTED TABLE table_attribute STORE AS attribute_nst;
```

---

How do I insert a VARCHAR2(100) into the nested table belonging to table_attribute?? What is the sintax??

Doing a simple insert like: `INSERT INTO attribute_nst VALUES ('some text');` gives the error

> cannot reference nested table column's storage table

What i want is to do insert from **within PROCEDURE doStuff(text VARCHAR2)**, i've tried:

```
INSERT INTO SELF.attribute_nst VALUES (text);
INSERT INTO attribute_nst VALUES (text);
INSERT INTO table_attribute VALUES (text);
```

...and other combination and no nothing, so please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY MY_OBJ AS
  2    member procedure doStuff(text varchar2) is
  3    begin
  4      table_attribute.extend(1);
  5      table_attribute(table_attribute.count) := text;
  6    end;
  7  end;
  8  /

Type body created.

SQL> declare
  2     l_my_obj My_Obj := My_Obj(1,MY_NESTED_TABLE_OBJ());
  3  begin
  4    l_my_obj.doStuff('abc');
  5    l_my_obj.doStuff('def');
  6
  7    insert into tbl_my_obj values (l_my_obj);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tbl_my_obj;

SIMPLE_ATRIBUTE
---------------
TABLE_ATTRIBUTE
------------------------------------------------------------
              1
MY_NESTED_TABLE_OBJ('abc', 'def')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
insert into tbl_my_obj  values (1, new my_nested_table_obj(text1, text2));

Comment: I do not want that. im thinking in a object oriented maner, I (X) am a instance of MY_OBJ... I have a method (procedure) doStuff(text VARCHAR2).... by using X.doStuff('a string') -> the 'a string' shoud go in my nested table